# A program to represent a coin amount using the smallest number of coins

Tags: algorithm, c, change-making-problem

Recently, I was learning about greedy algorithms. One example that was given was an algorithm for exchanging a given money amount using the smallest number of coins. After the lecture, I wrote a C program implementing this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

static int compareDenominations(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return (*((int*) b) - *((int*) a));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    long amount;
    int count;
    long *denominations;
    if (argc > 2) {
        errno = 0;
        amount = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
        if (errno || amount <= 0) {
            puts("The coin amount is either negative, zero, or too big.");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        count = argc - 2;
        if (count == 0) {
            puts("Please input at least one coin denomination.");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        denominations = malloc(sizeof(*denominations) * count);
        if (denominations == NULL) {
            puts("Insufficient memory.");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            errno = 0;
            denominations[i] = strtol(argv[i + 2], NULL, 10);
            if (errno || denominations[i] <= 0) {
                puts("A denomination amount is either negative, zero, or too big.");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            } else {
                int j;
                for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    if (denominations[j] == denominations[i]) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "%ld is a duplicate coin denomination.\n", denominations[j]);
                        return EXIT_FAILURE;
                    }                   
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        puts("Please enter a coin amount followed by a non-zero number of unique denominations, all separated by spaces.");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    heapsort(denominations, count, sizeof(*denominations), compareDenominations);
    printf("Amount: %ld | Denominations: [ ", amount);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%ld ", denominations[i]);
    }
    puts("]");
    int denominationCount = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        denominationCount = 0;
        while (amount >= denominations[i]) {
            amount -= denominations[i];
            denominationCount++;
        }
        denominations[i] = denominationCount;
    }
    if (amount) {
        puts("The coin amount could not be represented using the given denominations.");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("Counts: [ ");
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%ld ", denominations[i]);
    }
    puts("]");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Because my program can accept arbitrary inputs, this greedy algorithm may not *always* output the most optimal solution, but I am still interested in the quality of my implementation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Don't invent error messages. If `strtol` sets `errno`, use `perror()` to print a precise reason for a failure.
- Flat is better than nested. I recommend to handle `argc < 2` at the beginning, to remove one level of indentations of the main algorithm. Along the same line, there is no need to `else` once `if` branch does `return`.
- Testing for duplicated denomination is easier *after* they are sorted.
- `while (amount >= denominations[i])` loop is a long way to say

  ```
  denominationCount = amount / denomination[i];
  amount %= denomination[i];
  ```
- You may want to break the `for (i = 0; i < count; i++)` early, as soon as `amount` reaches 0.
- Qudos for `sizeof(*denominations)`.
- The algorithm may *fail to find* a solution.

Answer (score 6):

I understand that your focus might be on the implementation of the algorithm, however, I'm going to provide some feedback on code quality from things I've learned by reading *Clean Code*. I find it difficult to read and understand what's going on without looking carefully, which is an immediate [smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

#### `main`

Everything is happening in `main` and it's way too long.
Clean Code has this to say:

> "The flow of control is easy to follow. The main function builds the objects necessary for the system, then passes them to the application, which simply uses them." (Martin, 155)

- `main` should be short and simply call setup methods and pass them to run the application.

#### Functions

- The purpose of your program is to execute a greedy algorithm, right? At minimum this should be contained in a function with a descriptive name that handles the core of this logic - not in `main`.
- Functions should be small and do one thing. To refactor `main`, think about the various responsibilities going on and work on splitting them out to functions; a few examples: usage validation, the core algorithm logic, printing.

#### Usage

It's not immediately clear how to run the program - one has to examine the code to determine acceptable inputs for the usage.

- This should be documented in at the top as a comment and/or output by default, ideally by defining a function like `print_usage`. Common conventions exist for this - see [here](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/general/usage.html).
  Also note that someone else already pointed out that `puts("Please input at least one coin denomination.")` is confusing because it seems to imply stdin rather than argv.

#### Misc

- Clean Code introduces the *Newspaper Metaphor* which essentially says that code should read like a newspaper, top to bottom in order of increasing detail and order of execution flow. It follows then that `main` should be before `compareDenominations`.
- Consider adding some newlines between concepts to improve readabliity. Clean Code mentions *Vertical Openness Between Concepts*:

  > Nearly all code is read left to right and top to bottom. Each line represents an expression or a clause, and each group of lines represents a complete thought. Those thoughts should be separated from each other with blank lines. (Martin, 78)
- Use descriptive names. `int count` is too vague. Count of what? Descriptive, accurate naming is one of the key factors in writing readable code. I'd even argue that `amount` and `denominations` could be better. What specifically are they intended to represent?
- You seem to have mixed styles of defining variables at the beginning of function (old C convention) along with defining immediately before usage in some cases. This makes it a bit confusing when you look and see a new variable (`int denominationCount = 0;`). It's generally best to stay consistent. This is also compounded by the fact that `main` is so long.

Answer (score 5):

Since you have placed the declaration `int i` after a statement (which is only allowed in C99 and later), you can do it correctly by writing `for (int i = …`, which makes sure you don't accidentally use `i` outside the loop.

Error messages do not belong to `stdout`, they should be written to `stderr` instead.

The `Please enter` is misleading, since it refers to `argv` instead of `stdin`.

Each call to `malloc` must have a corresponding call to `free`, to prevent memory leaks. In this small program it may not matter, but in all functions other than `main` it is mandatory.